# Key error in iteration over list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, keyerror

I created a function in my class which adding in loop, a new pair key:value into dictionary.

```
def addFeature(self, *keys):

    for key in keys:
        print("key: {} \n".format(key))
        self.content[self.counter1].update(key)
```

There is how I use this function:

```
            self.addFeature(
                {'view':            self.dict_of_views['view{}'.format(self.counter2)]},
                {'link':            self.p.pr_link(self.content[self.counter1]['id'])})
```

And it works. But I faced a problem when I tried to call an key which is created in this loop function:

```
            self.addFeature(
                {'view':            self.dict_of_views['view{}'.format(self.counter2)]},
                {'link':            self.p.pr_link(self.content[self.counter1]['id'])},
                {'nsnManagerID':    self.ldap.ldap_searching(self.content[self.counter1]['author'])[1]},
                {'nsnManagerEmail': self.ldap.ldap_searching(self.content[self.counter1]['nsnManagerID'])}
```

It seemes that I can't call upon 'nsnManagerID' to get 'nsnManagerEmail' beacuse when I do this:

```
            self.addFeature(
                {'view':            self.dict_of_views['view{}'.format(self.counter2)]},
                {'link':            self.p.pr_link(self.content[self.counter1]['id'])},
                {'nation':          self.getNation(self.content[self.counter1]['author'])},
                {'email':           self.ldap.ldap_searching(self.content[self.counter1]['author'])[0]},
                {'nsnManagerID':    self.ldap.ldap_searching(self.content[self.counter1]['author'])[1]},
                )
            self.addFeature({'nsnManagerEmail': self.ldap.ldap_searching(self.content[self.counter1]['nsnManagerID'])})
```

Then it works...
Could you help me with the right way to do it? 
Just like I showed in third block of code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using the whole dictionary as a key?